# mysqltuner - Sorts requiring temporary tables

Tags: mysql, database, mysqltuner

I'm new to stackoverflow, so that's my first shot :)

I have an issue with my Mysql DB. I was running into some performance issues, so i decided to use mysqltuner. The Result is

```
[--] Up for: 7m 42s (7K q [16.452 qps], 78 conn, TX: 927K, RX: 2M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 86% / 14%
[--] Total buffers: 2.1G global + 1.1M per thread (151 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 2.3G (24% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (16/7K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 2% (4/151)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 1.0G/834.4M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 99.1% (8M cached / 79K reads)
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 0.0% (0 cached / 4K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[!!] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 376% (2K temp sorts / 675 sorts)
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (13 on disk / 7K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 94% (4 created / 78 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 26% (102 open / 384 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (63/5K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (13K immediate / 13K locks)
```

Obviously I'm having too many temporary tables created.

But what does that mean? Is that problem caused by a missing index or something?

I appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: You're using `ORDER BY` on a non-indexed column.

Comment: All columns are indexed. But i've some queries which are sorted by a `SUM()` clause. Could this also cause that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check limit for temporary table in memory to be sure than this point is not written table into disk.

https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/01/19/tmp_table_size-and-max_heap_table_size/